# Load elements without reload page

Tags: themes

At the outset, I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I have no idea what exactly I'm looking for.
I have page with categories like this
[image: category list]

My goal is when I click on category, page will not reload but will show me elements which are assigned to this category. Each category have one or more elements.
Someone can tell me what am I need. Example will be awesome!

Best Regards,
Bartek

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that either by loading all content at page-load but hiding contents till buttons are clicked like in this simple [example codepen](https://codepen.io/CthuKi/pen/YqZvRv).

Or if you have a lot of content like images that you do not want to load on page-load due to loading speed you could use ajax. But that's complicated for beginners. – Or first option with lazy-loading for the images...